# Converting Values of series with dictionary values to DataFrame. Not the Series itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have  series which looks like this:

```
d1 = {'Class': 'A', 'age':35, 'Name': 'Manoj'}
d2 = {'Class': 'B', 'age':15, 'Name': 'Mot'}
d3 = {'Class': 'B', 'age':25, 'Name': 'Vittoo'}

ser = [d1, d2, d3]

dummy = pd.Series(ser)
dummy
0     {'Class': 'A', 'age': 35, 'Name': 'Manoj'}
1     {'Class': 'B', 'age': 15, 'Name': 'Mot'}
2    {'Class': 'B', 'age': 25, 'Name': 'Vittoo'}
```

When I use the to_frame function, it does this:

```
dummy.to_frame()

                      0
0   {'Class': 'A', 'age': 35, 'Name': 'Manoj'}
1   {'Class': 'B', 'age': 15, 'Name': 'Mot'}
2   {'Class': 'B', 'age': 25, 'Name': 'Vittoo'}
```

But what I intent to get is this:

```
Class   Name    age
0   A   Manoj   35
1   B   Mot     15
2   B   Vittoo  25
```

I have tried this which works fine:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dummy)
df = df[0].apply(pd.Series)
df
```

But it feels very inefficient because I need to convert the Series to a dataframe and again apply the Series function to the complete dataframe. As I'm working with millions of rows, I'd like to know if there is a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DataFrame` constructor instead `Series` constructor:

```
d1 = {'Class': 'A', 'age':35, 'Name': 'Manoj'}
d2 = {'Class': 'B', 'age':15, 'Name': 'Mot'}
d3 = {'Class': 'B', 'age':25, 'Name': 'Vittoo'}

ser = [d1, d2, d3]

df = pd.DataFrame(ser)
print (df)
  Class    Name  age
0     A   Manoj   35
1     B     Mot   15
2     B  Vittoo   25
```

---

If input data is `Series` fiiled by dictionaries convert it to lists before `DataFrame` constructor, `to_frame` is not necessary:

```
dummy = pd.Series(ser)

df = pd.DataFrame(dummy.values.tolist())
print (df)
  Class    Name  age
0     A   Manoj   35
1     B     Mot   15
2     B  Vittoo   25
```

Comment: I have directly added the Series dummy to the constructor previously, which gave the same result as to_frame. Should I convert the series values to a list and then use the DataFrame constructor?

Comment: @MohitMotwani - yes, exactly. `df = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(ser).values.tolist())`